# Dynamic Input direct from user in console

Tags: c#, dynamic, console

In the following code;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dynamic x;
            x = Console.ReadLine(); //readline methode returns string.
            Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().ToString());
        }
```

I tried to make a simple concept where the user would like to enter 5 elements of different type data then each time would show up.

the thing is, ReadLine will always return value as string, I can use convert but still, this will force the user to enter the only convert type.

I have been searching but don't really know what to do cause I don't know how to express the question.

Is there is another method that can take input dynamically from user or a property I don't know about.

Comment: What type of other input did you expect?

Comment: int, float, char...Simple primary like.

Comment: How do you know if the input "5" is a char or int?

Comment: similar when initializing a var with value similar to 2.5, it will always choose double, not float or decimal.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no other method to accept user inputs from the console. It will always be text/string.

You'll have to parse the inputs from `Console.ReadLine()` from a string to whatever type you need. Your problem is there's no way of knowing what the type is if you just have a string. If the user input "2" did she mean the number 2 (int) or did she actually mean "2" (string).

Answer (score -1):

You can have limited success, but for reasons pointed out in comments, it will be limited to a few primitive types. For example, a float input can't be discriminated between Float32 and Float64

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    dynamic x;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out int a))
        x = a;
    else if (float.TryParse(input, out float b))
        x = b;
    else if (input.Length == 1)
        x = input[0];
    else
        x = input;

    Console.WriteLine($"{x}: {x.GetType()}");
}
```

> 5
>
> 5: System.Int32
>
> 6.9
>
> 6.9: System.Single
>
> f
>
> f: System.Char
>
> stri
>
> stri: System.String

Comment: Just want to add, I used `dynamic x` because you did, but `object x` would work just fine.